# Kerberos Authenticator Encryption Type NULL

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos, single-sign-on, windows-xp

So, I've been working on a SSO enabled XMPP application on our network for a couple weeks. I have 95% of the bugs worked out, and everything is running smoothly. The problem is that I have a couple machines that are not connecting, giving me the error `"SSO Failed, etc etc"`

I did a packet analysis, and on one machine, I am getting a packet with a Kerberos error `KDC_ERR_ETYPE_NOSUPP` which of course means that the server does not support the encryption type selected by the client.

**This is where this get's interesting.**

The request body portion of the packet sent from client to the Kerberos server shows that it is requesting encryption types that are most definitely supported by Kerberos, most notable `RC4-HMAC` **IS** being requested by the client.

I'm sure you can imagine I was quite confused when I saw that. So I compared the Kerberos request packet with the packet from another client that is functioning properly.

I found that in a portion the packet labeled as `padata` > `ap-req` > `authenticator` which you probably know is: `(pre-authentication > authentication protocol request > authenticator`) the requested encryption type is **`NULL`** !!!!

So, first of all, my other machines are using an appropriate encryption type for pre-authentication, and working just fine.

I have done nothing that I can imagine would have affected this configuration, considering that I hadn't worked on that system since I (recently) started here, nor do I have any idea where I could look to adjust that configuration. On some of our other systems there was a VPN installed that seemed to have been interfering with SSO, but that VPN was **NOT** installed on this system, and I have removed **EVERY** application aside from Microsoft Office. I also removed and re-added it to the domain, hoping that there would be some re-configuration that happened there.

How can I fix the pre-authentication protocol setting for this computer, aside from re-installing Windows?

Thanks!!

Comment: Not an answer, but I notice that you're using the XP tag.  XP is EoL.  Don't troubleshoot it, upgrade it. (Or take it out back and shoot it, if it's been particularly troublesome.)

Comment: As a possible answer, however, [check the registry key mentioned in this msdn blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2009/10/12/changes-in-default-encryption-type-for-kerberos-pre-authentication-on-vista-and-windows-7-clients-cause-security-audit-events-675-and-680-on-windows-server-2003-dc-s.aspx), to see if your misbehaving clients have no encryption or an invalid encryption type specified as the default for their Kerberos authentication.

Comment: I'm aware of the EOL issue. We are a non profit and work on limited funds. Perhaps you would donate a couple licenses for 7? There is no registry entry on any of the systems, working or not. I am going to add a registry entry and see if it produces a new result.

Comment: [Microsoft offers pretty steep discounts on software licensing for eligible non-profit organizations](http://www.microsoft.com/about/corporatecitizenship/en-us/nonprofits/whos-eligible/) and Linux is free.  Either option is generally preferable to running on an EoL platform.

Comment: Modifying the registry didn't help. Strangely, when I try to access a network share, SMB/NetBios are using the appropriate encryption mechanisms and are able to access anything on the network. The only issue is with this application using SSO. I'm reinstalling, but I think there is some underlying tangential issue